# Scrapy: output comparison of two spiders

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm learning to work with scrapy and as an exercise I'm writing spiders to crawl different websites. In this example: https://www.thuisbezorgd.nl/eten-bestellen-castricum and https://www.iens.nl/restaurant+zoetermeer. There are some things that I don't understand; let's compare these two spiders:

**Spider 1:**

```
import scrapy
from datetime import datetime
from scrapy import Request
import urllib.parse as urlparse
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from iensScraper.items import IensscraperItem
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class IensSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name ="ienzz"
    start_urls = ['https://www.iens.nl/restaurant+zoetermeer']

    domain = ['https://www.iens.nl/']

    def parse(self, response):
        restaurants = response.css('.resultItem')
        items = [(restaurant.css('[href]::text').extract_first(),restaurant.css('.resultItem-address::text').extract_first(),restaurant.css('.rating-ratingValue::text').extract_first(), restaurant.css('.reviewsCount>[href]::text').extract_first()) for restaurant in restaurants]
        for item in items:
            holder = ItemLoader(item=IensscraperItem(),response=response)
            holder.add_value('naam',item[0])
            holder.add_value('adres',item[1])
            holder.add_value('rating',item[2])
            holder.add_value('recensies',item[3])
            yield holder.load_item()

        if(response.xpath('//*[@class="next"]//@href').extract()):
            link = response.css('.next>a::attr(href)').extract()
            yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url,link[0]),callback=self.parse,dont_filter=True)

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(Iensspider)
process.start()
```

**Output spider 1:**

```
2017-01-19 11:48:20 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.iens.nl/restaurant+zoetermeer?page=2>
{'adres': ['\n'
           '                            Middelwaard 86 2716 CW Zoetermeer\n'
           '                                                    '],
 'naam': ['Meerzicht']}
2017-01-19 11:48:20 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.iens.nl/restaurant+zoetermeer?page=2>
{'adres': ['\n'
           '                            Burgemeester van Leeuwenpassage 2 2711 '
           'JV Zoetermeer\n'
           '                                                    '],
 'naam': ['Brandcafé Zoetermeer']}
2017-01-19 11:48:20 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.iens.nl/restaurant+zoetermeer?page=2>
{'adres': ['\n'
           '                            Van der Hagenstraat 22 2722 NT '
           'Zoetermeer\n'
           '                                                    '],
 'naam': ['Taste of Asia']}
```

**Spider 2:**

```
import scrapy
import urllib.parse as urlparse
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from thuisbezorgdscraper.items import ThuisbezorgdscraperItem
class ThuisSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spiderman'
    domain = ['https://www.thuisbezorgd.nl']
    start_urls = ['https://www.thuisbezorgd.nl/eten-bestellen-castricum']

    def parse(self, response):
        raw_urls = response.css('.delarea')
        urls = raw_urls.css('::attr(href)').extract()
        for url in urls:
            yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url),callback=self.parse_item, dont_filter=True)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        restaurants = response.css('.restaurant.grid')
        for restaurant in restaurants:
            l = ItemLoader(item=ThuisbezorgdscraperItem(), response=response)
            name = restaurant.css('.restaurantname[itemprop]::text').extract()
            address = restaurant.css('.restaurantaddress::text').extract()
            score = restaurant.css('.pointy::attr(title)').extract()
            reviews = restaurant.css('.nrofreviews::text').extract()
            l.add_value('address', address)
            l.add_value('name',name)
            l.add_value('score', score)
            l.add_value('reviews', reviews)
            yield l.load_item()

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(ThuisSpider)
process.start()
```

**Output spider 2:**

```
2017-01-19 11:12:06 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.thuisbezorgd.nl/eten-bestellen-castricum-castricum-zuid-1901>
{'address': ['\n\t\t      Rijksweg 2', '\t      '],
 'name': ['New York Pizza'],
 'reviews': ['200 recensies'],
 'score': ['Klantbeoordeling: 7 / 10']}
2017-01-19 11:12:06 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.thuisbezorgd.nl/eten-bestellen-castricum-castricum-noord-1902>
{'address': ['\n\t\t      Heemskerkerweg 93', '\t      '],
 'name': ['Fresco'],
 'reviews': ['1420 recensies'],
 'score': ['Klantbeoordeling: 8 / 10']}
2017-01-19 11:12:06 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.thuisbezorgd.nl/eten-bestellen-castricum-centrum-1901>
{'address': ['\n\t\t      Boulevard 13', '\t      '],
 'name': ['iSAFIA'],
 'reviews': ['285 recensies'],
 'score': ['Klantbeoordeling: 8 / 10']}
```

**Spider 1:** The first spider crawls the website 'iens' exactly like I want it to do; after it has parsed all the information from the start url, it uses indexation to move on to the next page to parse that page, etc. The functioning of this spider is confirmed by looking at the output. First all the restaurants on the initial page are returned, then all the restaurants on the second page are returned, until there are no more pages left.

**Spider 2:**
The second spider has a slightly different structure. It first extracts the desired urls from the start url and then starts scraping the extracted urls. I **want** this spider to act just like the first one; scrape all the restaurants from the first url, then scrape all the restaurants from the second url, until there are no more urls left. However, the second spider scrapes the restaurants from all the extracted urls simultaneously. This spider yields one restaurant from one extracted url, then yields another restaurant from a another extracted url, until there are no more restaurants left.

**Question:** Why do these spiders behave so differently? (The spiders have the same settings!)